# Jquery refresh select lists each second

Tags: php, jquery, refresh

I am working on an e-commerce project and I would like to set up 2 dropdown lists linked in ajax. The first list contains the products and the second one contains the quantity of each product.

There is a problem when a user selects a product and then a quantity, and, in the same time another user selects a product and then a quantity => the quantities are not correct. I will try to explain what I mean.

Imagine a first product named "A" with 2 quantities.
A first user choses this product and selects 1 quantity.
there is one quantity left for this product.
At this same very moment, if another user selects the same product, the quantities show "2" ! It is difficult to explain but I wonder if a timeout function should fix this.

Comment: Please create a https://jsfiddle.net/ to illustrate the problem or at the very least include the code in the question itself.

Comment: You're talking about race conditions. To be honest, your solution will not stop this issue and just adds a layer of complexity to your application for no real gain imo.

Answer (score 0):

You could use setTimeout to update the quantity drop down items every so often based on the product the user has currently selected however I think this a bit overkill.

You would also have to set and store on the server the quantity values every time the user changed their selection.

It is do-able but I would just re-validate the quantity the user has selected is still available once they submit the form.